# How to display data for individual days in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

In my database, I have the data in the below format:
[image: Database View]

and in my SSRS (2010) report, I need too show the data in the below format.
[image]

My question is: 
We have data in the database for each bussiness date. In the report the data is shown horizontally (Sunday - Saturday)..
So, when returning data from the DB, should I create individual columns for each day, update them with the data depending on the date and return it
in individual day columns(individual columns for each day).. or is there a way we can do that in SSRS?
The first option looks easier to do but not sure if it would be the right design.

Comment: Q1. If its 1 year worth of data would you restrict the report or will it show 365 columns? Q2. Are there days when nobody worked?

Comment: Just following up on the question from @AnupAgrawal, in your example there is one week's worth of data - will this always be the case? How do you specify which date period to use?

Comment: The data needs to be grouped into the days. Sorry I didnt frame the question correctly. But that was the actual issue. How to group the data into days in SSRS. If it is not possible in SSRS, then, I would have to group it in the Stored Proc and return 7 different columns for 7 days. As of now, I just have a BusinessDate column being returned.

Comment: Also, how would it work if I restrict the date range to only one week? The date range can start on any day but would always be one week.

Comment: did you try the below answer by **creating column groups**.

Answer (score 1):

Use Matrix.

Create row group of company, business unit and employee.

**Create column group** for `BusinessDate`. SSRS will automatically create columns for you.

Expression for the cell would be `=SUM(HoursWorked)`